# Issue with a WebApi action controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

my controller action:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPdf(int file)
```

the call ajax:

```
var self = this;
    var url = "api/pdfs/1";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data)...
```

The routing pattern:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I execute the code I have a HTTP 404 error.
Can someone see the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the method just be called `Get`?  What is the controller named?

Comment: The controller name is PdfsController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ongoing versions of WebAPI may have varying conventions, but I think the safest approach in simple cases is to name the method after the HTTP verb.  Additionally, note that your routing is expecting an `id` parameter:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

But you're naming your parameter `file` instead.  Combine these two suggestions and re-define your method as:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
```

Comment: OHHHH yes, the probleme is with the parameter, I must substitute it with file. Thank you very much.